# No add work profile on Samsung Galaxy S21+

Tags: samsung, work-profiles

I just bought Samsung Galaxy S21+ and I went to the manage accounts to add a work profile, but there is not an option to do so. I am wondering if I can download a newer version of Android to get this or if my phone needs updates.

What can I do to get the work profile option on my phone?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Access-Work-Profile-on-Android

Comment: Last week on my old phone I had a work profile. I followed the instructions you shared. And I do not have this option any longer for the work profile with my new phone..do you know why?

Comment: can't your IT department help?

Comment: Could you mention your old phone? Based on my experience, you just need to add the work account, then depending on the setting from your company, the work profile will (or won't) be created automatically.